# Jinja commented out commands breaks templating

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have been trying to automate a template for deploy by Ansible:

Inventory contents:

```
[splunk_license]
10.10.113.209

[splunk_master]

[splunk_search]
10.10.113.209

[splunk_indexer]
10.10.113.234
```

My template has logic based on whether the **splunk_master** group has a host defined or not.

*Original* code:

```
{% if inventory_hostname in groups['splunk_indexer'] and 
groups['splunk_master']|length > 0 %}
#{% if blah blah blah blah...%}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES go to $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf
# on Master node

{% elif inventory_hostname in groups['splunk_master'] %}
#{% if some other blah blah blah blah...%}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES go to $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf

{% else %}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES

[nothing]
coldToFrozenDir = $SPLUNK_DB/frozen/nothing/frozendb
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/hotwarm/nothing/thaweddb
coldPath = volume:secondary/nothing/colddb
homePath = volume:primary/nothing/db
{% endif %}
```

No matter what I did I could not get the bottom part after {% else %} to work. Turns out the commenting out '#' does not actually cause that line to be ignored, which I had for testing purposes as I was tired of typing stuffs out over and over.

I tried to modify my (uncommented) if statements every which way from Sunday and I would either get only the top part of template, an Ansible error complaining about unexpected 'elif' or groups not found errors.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with the community - I hope this saves people a lot of headache in the future! I’ve moved the part of your question that had the answer in it down to your answer and edited the title so that the information is a bit easier to find for future visitors. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask for help here but last minute tried to remove all commented lines out and now my template finally works.

Working code (commented lines removed):

```
{% if inventory_hostname in groups['splunk_indexer'] and 
groups['splunk_master']|length > 0 %}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES go to $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf
# on Master node

{% elif inventory_hostname in groups['splunk_master'] %}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES go to $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/master-apps/_cluster/local/indexes.conf

{% else %}
# CUSTOMER INDEXES

[nothing]
coldToFrozenDir = $SPLUNK_DB/frozen/nothing/frozendb
thawedPath = $SPLUNK_DB/hotwarm/nothing/thaweddb
coldPath = volume:secondary/nothing/colddb
homePath = volume:primary/nothing/db
{% endif %}
```

Apologies if this is Jinja's obvious behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja comments are as follows `{# comment #}` if using single `#` jinja will still evaluate those lines causing errors or a bad formatted destination file, see [Jinja Templating docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#comments)